# How to display git command results in User Interface(AngularJs/HTML)?

Tags: html, angularjs, git

I am getting resultant data for git command and I want to display that results in UI. For example consider I am giving $git diff --name-only in Git Bash and I am getting list of files which got modified.I want project that results in any UI(AngularJs/HTML).

Is it possible to do that? and if so kindly guide me how to do it?

Comment: You would typically be running the commands on a terminal and AngularJS/HTML in a browser, so I don't think its directly possible. You can save them to a file and read in AngularJS

Comment: Thanks Anurag..can you tell me how to save them to a file and read in AngulaJS?

Comment: You can find a lot of solutions with a simple Google search. :)